# Let $A$ be a $m×n$ matrix.
Define $V=\{y \in \Bbb R^m \mid Ax=y \ \text{has solutions}\}$.
Show that $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a $m×n$ matrix.
Define
$V=\{y \in \Bbb R^m \mid Ax=y \ \text{has solutions}\}$.
Show that $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$.

**Attempt:**
First, notice that $V$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^m$.
Denote $\mathbf{0_m}$ and $\mathbf{0_n}$ be the zero vectors in $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$, respectively.

1. Since $\mathbf{0_m} = A\mathbf{0_n}$, then $\mathbf{0_m} = Ax$ has a solution, that is, $x=\mathbf{0_n}$.
   Hence, $\mathbf{0_m} \in V$ and therefore, $V \ne \emptyset$.
2. Let $y_1,y_2 \in V$. Then, there exists $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax_1=y_1$ and $Ax_2=y_2$. Let $x=x_1+x_2$. Then,
   \begin{equation*}
   Ax = A(x_1+x_2) = Ax_1 + Ax_2 = y_1+y_2.
   \end{equation*}
   Hence, $y_1+y_2 \in V$.
3. Let $y_1 \in V$. Then, there exists $x_1 \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax_1=y_1$. Let $c$ be an arbitrary scalar. Let $x=cx_1$, a vector in $\Bbb R^n$. Then, we have
   \begin{equation*}
   Ax = A(cx_1) = c(Ax_1) = cy_1.
   \end{equation*}
   Hence, $cy_1$ is in $V$.

Thus, $V$ is a subspace $\Bbb R^m$.

Am I true?

Comment: Very well done.

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks Sir!